# Calculating the distribution function of multiple random variables

Tags: probability

When working through my probability course, I recently came across multidimensional distributions. In the beginning of this chapter, my book defines the distribution function as

$F_{\mathbb{X,Y}}(x,y) = Pr(\mathbb{X}\le x,\mathbb{Y}\le y)$

The density function was defined as

$f_{\mathbb{X,Y}}(x,y) = {\delta^2F_{\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y}}(x,y)\over\delta x\delta y}$

from which it then follows that

$F_{\mathbb{X,Y}}(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{\mathbb{X,Y}}(u,v)dudv=1$

I understand the definitions, but the problem here is that I haven't studied calculus with multiple varibles, so I have no clue whatsoever how to derive an expression with multiple varibles.

To make this easier to understand, the book provided an example. In this example we are given that

$f_{\mathbb{X,Y}}(x,y) = 2e^{-x-2y}, x\ge0,y\ge0$

The book then proceedes to calculate the distribution function:

$F_{\mathbb{X,Y}}(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^x f_{\mathbb{X,Y}}(u,v)dudv = \int_0^y\int_0^x 2e^{-u-2v}dudv=\int_{v=0}^y\left[-2e^{-u-2v}\right]dv=...=(1-e^{-x})(1-e^{-2y})$

The step between $\int_0^y\int_0^x 2e^{-u-2v}dudv=\int_{v=0}^y\left[-2e^{-u-2v}\right]dv$ is what I don't understand, and I believe (and hope) that if I got this step explained to me, I'll find it easier to understand the rest as well.

So, my question is really just how

$\int_0^y\int_0^x 2e^{-u-2v}dudv=\int_{v=0}^y\left[-2e^{-u-2v}\right]dv$

makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a closer look, and some trial and error testing, I realized my own mistake. The problem is that I am considering

$\int_0^y\int_0^x2e^{-u-2v}dudv$

as a two dimensional expression, which it is de facto not; when integrating the expression, we begin by integrating

$\int_0^x2e^{-u-2v}du$

which has one variable, $u$, and one unknown constant, $v$. Looking at it like this, it is easy to see that

$\int_0^x2e^{-u-2v}du = \left[-2e^{-u-2v}\right]$

since

${\delta\over\delta u}(-u-2v) = -1$

and thusly

${\delta\over\delta u}(-2e^{-u-2v}) = 2e^{-u-2v}$

which fits perfectly.